# Where are EE's native Snippets saved, locationwise?

Tags: ee2, snippets

I just moved a site to another server and *duh!* forgot to copy over the Snippets manually. Don't ask.

I have a full backup though, ftp as well as sql. Now I am wondering where the native EE Snippets are being stored. I searched through all files and directories I could think of but I am unable to find any trace.

Also I couldn't really find anything in the sql dump.

Anybody know where they are being stored for sure?

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're stored in the `exp_snippets` database table.

Comment: Thanks Low, I found 'em. Must have overlooked them before because of the additional "/n's" that were put in the dump, so that it didn't look "right" to me. :-)